# Setting initial text Social Frameworks iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios6

How can I add an UILabel value in addition to my `setInitialText` string for tweet/fb composer sheet.

Ive tried adding `myUILabel.text` in a variety of ways that end up with either a crash or data argument not used so far

```
   mySLComposerSheet = [[SLComposeViewController alloc] init];
   mySLComposerSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]; ///
   [mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:@"My message"]; ///can I add UI label value here?
   [self presentViewController:mySLComposerSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Why `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"My message"]`? Why not simply `@"My message"`?

Comment: Anyway, `label.text` should work fine, except if you fail to manage memory correctly and the label is prematurely deallocated.

Comment: HC, yes that would be cleaner implementation. Thanks for tip. fixed it now

Answer (score 0):

Ah fixed it after ages, needed placeholder

```
[mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"My message %@",_myUILable.text]];
```